# flutter screen doesn't update using setState and tryParse

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-state

I'm trying to build a simple Calculator with flutter. The prototype I've created isn't able the update the Screen, when using a setState and tryParse. I want to show the number a user presses instantly on the screen and when pressing another number, all the numbers get converted into one chain using tryPars.(....join()) (1 + 3 + 7 = 137). However, my first try isn't working (Code in `num_pad.dart`). What did I do wrong?

`landing_page.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';

import '../responsive_layout.dart';
import 'Widgets/build_column.dart';

class LandingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LandingPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LandingPage> createState() => _LandingPageState();
}

class _LandingPageState extends State<LandingPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[800],
        title: const Text(
          "Calculator",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
        ),
      ),
      body: const BuildColumn(),
    );
  }
}
```

`build_column.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../responsive_layout.dart';
import 'num_pad.dart';

List<double> firstInput = [];
int? outputNumber = 0;
class BuildColumn extends StatefulWidget {
  const BuildColumn({
    Key? key,
  

  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BuildColumn> createState() => _BuildColumnState();
}



class _BuildColumnState extends State<BuildColumn> {
  
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Container(
        width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
        height: SizeConfig.screenHeight / 3,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
        child:  Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Text(
              "$outputNumber",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
        child: Container(
          width: SizeConfig.screenWidth * 0.85,
          
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border(top: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.grey)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 5),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child:  NumPadBuild(),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ]);
  }
  
}
```

`num_pad.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/ui/Widgets/build_column.dart';

class NumPadBuild extends StatefulWidget {
  const NumPadBuild({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NumPadBuild> createState() => _NumPadBuildState();
}

class _NumPadBuildState extends State<NumPadBuild> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, children: [
          numPadButton("C", const Color.fromARGB(136, 0, 0, 0),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 39, 36, 36), 0),
          numPadButton("7", const Color.fromARGB(136, 0, 0, 0),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 88, 85, 85), 7),
          numPadButton("4", const Color.fromARGB(136, 0, 0, 0),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 88, 85, 85), 4),
          numPadButton("1", const Color.fromARGB(136, 0, 0, 0),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 88, 85, 85), 1),
          numPadButton("0", const Color.fromARGB(136, 0, 0, 0),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 88, 85, 85), 0),
        ]),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, children: [
          numPadButton("±", const Color.fromARGB(137, 34, 33, 33),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 39, 36, 36), 0),
          numPadButton("8", const Color.fromARGB(136, 0, 0, 0),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 88, 85, 85), 8),
          numPadButton("5", const Color.fromARGB(136, 0, 0, 0),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 88, 85, 85), 5),
          numPadButton("2", const Color.fromARGB(136, 0, 0, 0),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 88, 85, 85), 2),
              numPadButton("√", const Color.fromARGB(136, 0, 0, 0),
              Color.fromARGB(255, 88, 85, 85), 2)
          
        ]),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, children: [
          numPadButton("%", const Color.fromARGB(137, 34, 33, 33),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 39, 36, 36), 0),
          numPadButton("9", const Color.fromARGB(137, 34, 33, 33),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 88, 85, 85), 9),
          numPadButton("6", const Color.fromARGB(137, 34, 33, 33),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 88, 85, 85), 6),
          numPadButton("3", const Color.fromARGB(137, 34, 33, 33),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 88, 85, 85), 3),
          numPadButton(",", const Color.fromARGB(136, 0, 0, 0),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 88, 85, 85), 0),
        ]),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, children: [
          numPadButton("÷", const Color.fromARGB(137, 34, 33, 33),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 235, 141, 1), 0),
          numPadButton("x", const Color.fromARGB(137, 34, 33, 33),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 235, 141, 1), 0),
          numPadButton("-", const Color.fromARGB(137, 34, 33, 33),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 235, 141, 1), 0),
          numPadButton("+", const Color.fromARGB(137, 34, 33, 33),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 235, 141, 1), 0),
          numPadButton("=", const Color.fromARGB(137, 34, 33, 33),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 235, 141, 1), 0)
        ]),
      ),
    ]);
  }

  Container numPadButton(String buttonName, Color buttonColorBorder,
      Color buttonColor, double numPadValue) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: buttonColor,
            border: Border.all(color: buttonColorBorder.withOpacity(0.5))),
        child: Center(
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: ()  {
              setState(() {
                firstInput.add(numPadValue);
                outputNumber = int.tryParse(firstInput.join());
              });
              
            },
            child: Text(
              buttonName,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you like to update `BuildColumn` UI, but you are calling `setState` inside `NumPadBuild`. It will be good to start [state-management](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro) like [riverpod](https://riverpod.dev/)/[bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc), For now you can use callback method for small cases like this. And avoid using global variables.

```dart
class NumPadBuild extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(double tappedNumber) callback;

  const NumPadBuild({
    required this.callback,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NumPadBuild> createState() => _NumPadBuildState();
}
```

And on button

```dart
child: TextButton(
  onPressed: () {
    widget.callback(numPadValue);
  },
  child: Text(
    buttonName,
    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
  ),
```

The  `BuildColumn` state will update from this callback.

```dart
class _BuildColumnState extends State<BuildColumn> {
  List<double> firstInput = [];
  int? outputNumber = 0;
 //......

child: NumPadBuild(
  callback: (numPadValue) {
    firstInput.add(numPadValue);
    outputNumber = int.tryParse(firstInput.join());

    setState(() {});
  },
),
```

```dart
class BuildColumn extends StatefulWidget {
  const BuildColumn({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BuildColumn> createState() => _BuildColumnState();
}

class _BuildColumnState extends State<BuildColumn> {
  List<double> firstInput = [];
  int? outputNumber = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Text(
              "$outputNumber",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
        child: Container(
          width: 333,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border(top: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.grey)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: NumPadBuild(
              callback: (numPadValue) {
                firstInput.add(numPadValue);
                outputNumber = int.tryParse(firstInput.join());

                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ]);
  }
}

class NumPadBuild extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(double tappedNumber) callback;

  const NumPadBuild({
    required this.callback,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NumPadBuild> createState() => _NumPadBuildState();
}

class _NumPadBuildState extends State<NumPadBuild> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, children: [
          numPadButton("C", const Color.fromARGB(136, 0, 0, 0),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 39, 36, 36), 0),
          numPadButton("7", const Color.fromARGB(136, 0, 0, 0),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 88, 85, 85), 7),
          numPadButton("4", const Color.fromARGB(136, 0, 0, 0),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 88, 85, 85), 4),
          numPadButton("1", const Color.fromARGB(136, 0, 0, 0),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 88, 85, 85), 1),
          numPadButton("0", const Color.fromARGB(136, 0, 0, 0),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 88, 85, 85), 0),
        ]),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, children: [
          numPadButton("±", const Color.fromARGB(137, 34, 33, 33),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 39, 36, 36), 0),
          numPadButton("8", const Color.fromARGB(136, 0, 0, 0),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 88, 85, 85), 8),
          numPadButton("5", const Color.fromARGB(136, 0, 0, 0),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 88, 85, 85), 5),
          numPadButton("2", const Color.fromARGB(136, 0, 0, 0),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 88, 85, 85), 2),
          numPadButton("√", const Color.fromARGB(136, 0, 0, 0),
              Color.fromARGB(255, 88, 85, 85), 2)
        ]),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, children: [
          numPadButton("%", const Color.fromARGB(137, 34, 33, 33),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 39, 36, 36), 0),
          numPadButton("9", const Color.fromARGB(137, 34, 33, 33),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 88, 85, 85), 9),
          numPadButton("6", const Color.fromARGB(137, 34, 33, 33),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 88, 85, 85), 6),
          numPadButton("3", const Color.fromARGB(137, 34, 33, 33),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 88, 85, 85), 3),
          numPadButton(",", const Color.fromARGB(136, 0, 0, 0),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 88, 85, 85), 0),
        ]),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, children: [
          numPadButton("÷", const Color.fromARGB(137, 34, 33, 33),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 235, 141, 1), 0),
          numPadButton("x", const Color.fromARGB(137, 34, 33, 33),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 235, 141, 1), 0),
          numPadButton("-", const Color.fromARGB(137, 34, 33, 33),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 235, 141, 1), 0),
          numPadButton("+", const Color.fromARGB(137, 34, 33, 33),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 235, 141, 1), 0),
          numPadButton("=", const Color.fromARGB(137, 34, 33, 33),
              const Color.fromARGB(255, 235, 141, 1), 0)
        ]),
      ),
    ]);
  }

  Container numPadButton(String buttonName, Color buttonColorBorder,
      Color buttonColor, double numPadValue) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: buttonColor,
            border: Border.all(color: buttonColorBorder.withOpacity(0.5))),
        child: Center(
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              widget.callback(numPadValue);
            },
            child: Text(
              buttonName,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```